# How to do vertical scrolling in Android app using Python-Appium client

Tags: python, selenium, appium

I am working on python and appium as server. i want to automate a app. There is a page called Friend List which consists large number of friends. I want to scroll the friend list to each and every contact. Please help someone how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
driver.execute_script("mobile: scrollTo", {"element": <webdriver object element>.id})
```

More information about your problem here : https://discuss.appium.io/t/how-to-scroll-in-appium-using-python/1180/18

Comment: I used it but didn't help me to find a solution. I have a screenshot of UI auomator. In that screenshot u can see list of friends and i want to go to each and every friend using swipe or scroll. Please help me how to do this.Please check above screenshot.